# Blackberry ConnectionDescriptor null for mobile network

Tags: blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

I need to establish an HTTP connection on my blackberry device.
The following is my code ::

```
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
connDesc = connFact.getConnection(getUrl);
```

This code works fine when mobile network and wifi is on, or even if only wifi is on, but I get ConnectionDescriptor = null when I run the application only on mobile network.

I am using BIS-C plan, I do not understand why do I get ConnectionDescriptor as null, when I can access other web pages outside my application on mobile network.

I tried appending ";deviceside=false" to url, but it did not help either.
I need to accept push and hit a few urls using mobile network, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
connFact.setTransportTypeOptions(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, 
            new BisBOptions("<here is key to use BIS-B access on the device>"));
```

Comment: Hey Eugen what key are you talking about? I never entered any key to access BIS on my device. My service provider activated it for me.

Comment: BIS-B is not available for third party apps by default (even when it's available on the device).

Comment: Ok. But i just want to know where can I get the key to use BIS-B from? or what parameter should I pass to BisBOptions("") ?

Comment: To get this key you have to: 1) become RIM alliance member (what is expensive for indy developer); 2) Google it (there are plenty of code available that exposes it). Sorry I can't give it directly

Comment: Can I access internet in application by setting permissions using ApplicationPermissionsManager

Comment: First you have to get user permission to use network. Second to use BIS-B transport you need key. you don't need key to use WiFi, DirectTCP, BES.

Comment: @Silent Screamer Try `new BisBOptions("mds-public")`